# Making my own NAS/Web server

Tags: networking, nas, media

I currently have a PC with 8GB RAM and haswell pentium cpu.

I need to it to serve these purposes:

- Act as media PC for my TV.

  - Will store my media files
  - Need to be able to access the drives over LAN from another PC within the same network
- Web server (on virtual machine)

  - Nginx + gunicorn  to run Django powered website. (staging server)
- Private cloud.

Considering the needs, could you guys suggest what kind of OS + software combination?

Comment: you are really mixing roles using it as a media PC and a server. Generally I would consider that an unsafe combination, as the desktop roles make stripping down and securing the server and the network much less effective. consider using a VPN instead of exposing your services publicly. that said, most main stream linux distros would provide you everything you need. the multimedia experience will be a little less smooth than windows, but it will run your server software with no trouble.

Comment: You **could** run Windows as your host machine so you get the benefit of Windows for your TV and (using VirtualBox) install your Linux distro of choice as a guest OS, sort out the port forwarding so that your external traffic is directed to your Linux and you'll have the best of both worlds. I, too, would also recommend a VPN for any secure connection you require. The virtual server should be safe to have a public access, though, just so long as you block public access to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably run a Windows server OS of some kind. You might be able to get decent usage out of a Windows server 2012. By using Windows server, you would be able to utilize Hyper-V as a virtualization platform to run the other OSes.

In terms of hardware, I would use two different NICs, one for the host os to connect to the LAN, and then use a separate NIC for the VMs. This can allow you to segment the host traffic and the VM traffic. While it is possible to utilize one NIC to do both, I prefer this configuration. That being said, you can choose to use only one NIC and then simply utilize it in a bridged manner.

You can get away with using something like Virtualbox instead of Hyper-V, however launching Virtualbox in headless mode cannot be done from a GUI, you will have to use a script in that case.

Of course, make sure that there are appopriate security measure in place, on your firewall and on the local machine to ensure people cannot exploit the public services to get access to the internal resources.